# How to make options from select directive bound with another array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Update: here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertyoung/jwTU2/9/

I'm building a webpage/app using AngularJS.

The function I want is, when the user add a row to the timecards table, he is able to choose one guy's name from the select picklist, and then the corresponding title of that guy would be shown after the name automatically.

And at the same time, the name and title of that guy need to be bound with another array (timecard.name and timecard.title). Is that possible? I've tried the following code and played around with it without any luck.

```
<div ng-repeat="for timecard in timecards">
  <td> 
     <span class="nullable">
       <select ng-model="timecard.name" ng-options="contact.name for contact in contacts">
         <option value="">Name</option>
       </select>
     </span>
  </td>

  <td> 
    <!-- The title of that corresponding contact should shown here -->
  </td> 

  <td>
    <input ng-model="timecard.totalHours" type="number"/> 
  </td>
</div>
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.contacts = [
   {name:"Jack", title:"Driver"},
   {name:"Mike", title:"Technician"},
   {name:"Lucy", title:"Engineer"}
];
$scope.timecards = [];
```

after the user complete the form, I want the data to look like:

```
$scope.timecards = [
   {name:"Jack", title:"Driver", totalHours:1},
   {name:"Mike", title:"Technician", totalHours:2},
   {name:"Lucy", title:"Engineer", totalHours:3}
];
```

Comment: Would you mind recreating this in jsfiddle or plnkr? It would be much faster for everyone to help you.

Comment: @Shomz Thanks! jsfiddle link added now.

Comment: Here is the perfect solution based on user3281440's answer:http://jsfiddle.net/robertyoung/jwTU2/20/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed ngModel in select to work the way you want, try the code below in  your fiddle. Anyway i guess what you really wants is to dynamically add timecard objects.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="timecardCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="timecard in timecards">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <td style="width:30%">Name</td>
            <td style="width:30%">Title</td>
            <td>Total Hours</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> 
                    <span class="nullable">
                        <select ng-model="timecard" ng-options="contact.name for contact in contacts">
                            <option value="">Name</option>
                        </select>
                    </span>
                </td>

                <td>
                    {{timecard.title}}<!-- The title of that corresponding contact should shown here -->
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input ng-model="timecard.totalHours" type="number" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{timecard}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a little change to @user3281440 's code

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="timecardCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="timecard in timecards">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <td style="width:30%">Name</td>
        <td style="width:30%">Title</td>
        <td>Total Hours</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> 
                <span class="nullable">
                    <select ng-model="timecard" ng-options="contact.name for contact in contacts">
                        <option value="">{{timecard.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </span>
            </td>

            <td>
                {{timecard.title}}<!-- The title of that corresponding contact should shown here -->
            </td>

            <td>
                <input ng-model="timecard.totalHours" type="number" />
            </td>
            <td>
                {{timecard}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But it STILL has one drawback, which is there is one unnecessary empty option in the picklist.

Comment: Just remove <option value="">Name</options> if you don't want empty option. Check Angular select documentation. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: @user3281440 <option value="">{{timecard.name}}</option> this line of code will make the name shown every time when page is loaded. If it is deleted, the name will not be shown correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/robertyoung/jwTU2/18/

Comment: Rongbo, what makes one of the select options "Active" is the value assigned to ngModel variable, <option value="">--select one--</option> is used only to add a null value option to the list, please check the angular select doc I suggested before.